# Ckeckbox marcados com Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Boa tarde
Tenho um estrutura HTML montadada dentro de um ng-repeat que cria ckeckboxes na horizontal e vertical, ou seja, um array multidimensional. Quando eu clico em um, eu tenho que salvar no banco. Até ai tudo bem, o problema está sendo para trazer esses checkbox marcados, pois no método que eu trago os resultados, o array do model me da como indefinido. Segue o link dos códigos:

http://jsfiddle.net/8eepu0o8/

Comment: Sem saber o formato do que estás a receber, é um bocado dificil nós ajudarmos-te..

Comment: Adicione nos seus checkboxes as opções `ng-true-value="true"` e
       `ng-false-value="false"`. Verifique também se ao recuperar o valor do json o valor `true` se altera para `"true" (string)` ou `1 (inteiro)` ou `"1" (string)`.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, mas a sua solução não funcionou @EduardoLelis, coloca ng-true-value="true" e ng-false-value="false" no campo.